# How to add image or icon to a button

Tags: c#

I'm new in C#. I want to insert image or icons to buttons in my form. I have tried using button properties but it gives unpredictable results.Can anyone suggest, how I can do it?

Comment: Explain how you tried usiing the Properties and which and what you mean by unpredictable results!

Comment: never mind i just followed below steps it worked

Comment: Fine. BTW there are two images you can assign to a Button, BackgroundImage and Image..

Comment: how does image work ??

Comment: please post come code example of what you already tried.

Comment: It is similar but meant to be added to the Text. BackgroundImage is meant to cover the whole button, so you can tile a background pattern and have a centered Image. Look at the BackgroundImageLayout options! Image can be from an indexed ImageList and it also has an ImageAlign property, so you can make it fit on the Butoon alson with the Text and its Align property..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by either setting the button BackgroundImage property from your properties window or you can do this programmatically like for this sample below:

button1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"Absolute_Path_Of_Image");

or u can also add the image(s) to 'Resources' of ur project and then set the background image source from there this way the image stays in ur project and can move with your project

this.button1.BackgroundImage = NameSpace1.Properties.Resources.UntitledImage2;